# Spring security duplicated RemeberMeProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I build an application with GWT on client side (in future I rewrite interface to JS) and duplicate functionality by REST requests. Based on Spring framework.
Now I need to implement authorization.

Here is my security-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 ..........>
<security:http auto-config="false">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.html"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/mainGWT.html**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
</security:http>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.damintsev.servlet.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</bean>
<bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg name="key" value="rock"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.login"/>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class=
       "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <property name="key" value="rock"/>
    <property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="5000"/>
    <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="rememberMeFilter" class=
        "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="providerManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
            <ref bean="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider#0"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
</security:authentication-manager>
```

But rememberMe services didnt work. So I start to debug this and I found that `rememberMeAuthenticationProvider` initializes twise!! 
At first time initializes with name `org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider#0` and strange (autogenerated maybe) `key`.

The second provider initializes with propertly name `rememberMeAuthenticationProvider` with propertly key.

Later there is a problem because `key` in `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` didnt match with `rememberMeAuthenticationProvider`. 
But when I change name of bean to `org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider#0` it works fine.

What am I doing wrong ? Who initialize provider twise ?

```
<spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Second part of question: I dont understand how set RememberMe cookie to client so I write class. And if from client I receive remember = true I call that methood. And It works. If You provide some exmples with remeber me + REST it will helps.

```
 @Component
 public class Security {

    @Autowired
    private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

    public void remeberMe(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication1) {
        rememberMeServices.setAlwaysRemember(true);
        rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, authentication1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bean called `rememberMeAuthenticationProvider` and you are also using the namespace `remember-me` element which will also create one, hence the duplicate. You've also declared a filter which won't be used unless you actually insert it into the filter chain.

Either remove the namespace element and declare all the beans fully yourself, or stick with the namespace and let it do the work. If you want to customize the `RememberMeServices` you can you can retain that and the `services-ref` as you have it, but it's not clear from your question why you need to customize things.

If a remember-me cookie is sent by the client then the server will process it regardless of the type of client. How it is set in the first place depends on the login mechanism. Form login processing will automatically invoke the `RememberMeServices` and set the cookie if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! I remove namespace, and spring didnot create another provider. But I dont understand how I need to set cookie to cient without any login form. I mean that client send me a JSON like ({login: "..", pswd: "..", remeber: true}). And I want to authenticate it and send cookie.

Comment: If you haven't got as far as authenticating the client, I'd suggest you get that working before trying to set up remember-me. If you want to send a JSON message to log in then you'll have to use a custom authentication filter to handle this. But why send JSON when you can just post a request and have the standard filter handle it? There doesn't actually have to be a form involved. Alternatively use Basic authentication. The setup will also depend on whether you want the application to have a session or not.